# Docusign API Ruby: How to set predefined Custom Fields for an Envelope creation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docusignapi

I created some enveloppe custom fields in the admin of Docusign.
So I'd to know how to set their value when I create an enveloppe from the docusign Ruby API.

[image]

I've tried to set there like this, but it doesn't work. When I send the envelope the custom fields are not filled.

```rb
envelope_definition = DocuSign_eSign::EnvelopeDefinition.new

custom_fields = DocuSign_eSign::CustomFieldsEnvelope.new(
{"name":"enveloppe_annee","value":"2019"}
)

envelope_definition.custom_fields = [custom_fields]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `envelope_definition.custom_fields` attribute takes a single instance of `custom_fields`. (Not an array)

`custom_fields` is an object that has two attributes:

`list_custom_fields` wants an **array** of `ListCustomField`

`text_custom_fields` wants an **array** of `TextCustomField`

Based on the above, can you redo your request?

Comment: Thanks for your precisions ! 
So i'd like to set the customs fields of a new envelope (before send it). I don't understand how to set the values with the ruby sdk...

Comment: Hmmm, I haven't written ruby code for about a decade. I'll give it a go when I have a bit of time.

Answer (score 0):

```rb
envelope_definition = DocuSign_eSign::EnvelopeDefinition.new({status: 'sent', templateId:'a19dXXXX-XXXX-4ce7-XXXX-56cXXXX83364', emailSubject: 'Example Document Signing'})
signer = DocuSign_eSign::TemplateRole.new({email: 'email@eample.com', name: 'Johny Walker', roleName: 'signer'})
text = DocuSign_eSign::Text.new
text.tab_label = 'label_id of the custom field'
text.value = 'value for the custom field'
tabs = DocuSign_eSign::Tabs.new
tabs.text_tabs = [text]
signer.tabs = tabs
envelope_definition.template_roles = [signer]
```

This should work for you